# Mock external web service calls in integration testing Play 2.4.X

Tags: playframework, integration-testing, playframework-2.4

I am working with microservices and I want to write integration test for it. 
My microservices runs on port no. 9000, 9001. So I want to test my routes of port 9000 but it internally calls my service which runs on 9001, so I get connection refused error, I want to mock specific calls which hits 9001.
I have tried [play-mockws](https://github.com/leanovate/play-mockws) and [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [rest-client-driver](https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver) - this lets you mock external services that can be called over HTTP.

Add the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.rest-driver" % "rest-client-driver" % "1.1.44
```

Add the following to your test class.

```
@org.junit.Rule
public ClientDriverRule clientDriver = new ClientDriverRule(9001);
```

For each test method, you can then set expectations on `clientDriver` - the `@Rule` annotation takes care of resetting the client driver between tests.

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
   clientDriver.addExpectation(onRequestTo("/service/echo")
                               .withMethod(Method.POST)
                               .withBody("foo",
                                         "text/plain"),
                               giveResponse("bar"));

    // ...the rest of your test
}
```

Comment: I got this "unexpected request(s):" error, I guess because of it is asking me to construct request exact same. (ex. headers, content-type, connection: "keep-alive", user-agent: "AHC/1.0",accept: "*/*")

Comment: `ClientDriverRequest` follows the builder pattern, so you can just write one method to apply all the boilerplate of the request and then add specifics in the test methods.

Comment: Can you give any reference, like how to reduce this unwanted data in request?

Comment: That data will be present in your real application, so you should attempt to model it in the tests if necessary. Set a breakpoint to pull all the data out of the request, and use it to configure your tests.

Comment: I tried to construct the request like setting header through a java Map but actual request and the request which is created by me in the test cases is different like in actual request the connection:Keep-alive but in my test cases it was like this connection:"keep-alive". There is "" diffrence in both., I guess thats why I am not able to mock it.

Comment: I've never come across a request I couldn't match.  Set the logging level to INFO and you should get a clearer idea of what's happening.  See https://github.com/rest-driver/rest-driver/blob/master/rest-client-driver/src/main/java/com/github/restdriver/clientdriver/DefaultRequestMatcher.java#L197